# ¿Como reemplazo el segundo caracter repetido en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una función para validar un correo electrónico en un input.
Quiero que cuando el usuario ponga un segundo arroa el input no se lo permita.
Se que con la función .replace() se puede reemplazar un caracter o cadena que uno guste.
Ejemplo:

`correo.replace(/[@]/,"")//Así permito que solo se pueda poner solo un arroa`
`correo.replace(/[@]/g,"")//Así no permito que se pueda poner ningún arroa`

Con el ejemplo 1 si dejo un arroa sucederia esto:
`let correo = "correo@gmail@.com";`
`console.log(correo)`
`//Respuesta Consola: correogmail@.com`
`//Quiero que saque el segundo arroa para que se vea así`
`//correo@gmail.com`

¿Como puedo reemplazar el segundo arroa por ""?

Gracias por su tiempo y gestión

Comment: Buen día, si únicamente evalúas el segundo arroba ¿Qué sucede si el usuario escribe `corr@eo@gmail.com`?

Comment: ¿Y si le pones un `type="email"` como atributo al input y te ahorras validaciones extra?  Aquí tienes documentación al respecto:  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Creo que la forma como estás intentando resolver tu validación podría mejorarse.

Si en tu función para validar el correo electrónico lo que estas haciendo es "intentar" corregir los errores del usuario entonces no es validación, sería intentar adivinar qué hizo mal el usuario y luego intentar escribir el correo electrónico de forma correcta

Las funciones de validación lo que deben hacer es decirte si la entrada cumple con todas las normas de validación o si falla, en caso de que falle entonces regresar un valor `null` o `false`

Un método muy usado para validación, son las expresiones regulares (Regex, del inglés "regular expresions").

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo comprobado para validar email:

```
const validarEmail = (email) => {
    return String(email)
       .toLowerCase()
       .match(
           /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        );
};
```

Ahora, si de verdad quieres reemplazar la segunda ocurrencia, podrías hacer algo así:

```
const resultado = text.replace(/@/g, match => ++t === 2 ? '' : match)
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo aquí una solución al problema del segundo @ que planteas, ten en cuenta que este código solo soluciona el problema de mas de un arroba, en caso de tener mas de uno avisa que el correo es invalido.

Tip extra, no intentes corregir el input del usuario, eso puede llevar a problemas mas adelante, tu tienes que educar al usuario a ingresar el formato que corresponde.

```
let correo = 'prueba@gmail.com'

correo.replace(/[^@]/g,'').length === 1 ? console.log('correo valido') : console.log('correo invalido')
```